Fitting a Nonlinear Mixed Model
I’m trying to fit a nonLinear Mixed Model (nLMM) to test whether the abundance of certain organisms was affected by the sampling period after an event that caused a significant increase.
The data show an important curve where the abundance of these organisms surged after the event (event between sampling_period: -1 and 1) but then declined.
I’m trying to construct a nonLinear Mixed Model, but I’ve found it quite challenging to understand how to build the model (e.g., model <- lmer(abundance ~ sampling_period + (1 | rep), data = data). I’d really appreciate any help in determining whether the abundance was affected by the sampling period.
data <- data.frame(
  abundance = c(79, 72, 58, 61, 88, 123, 119, 96, 67, 78, 143, 75, 105, 46, 58, 
                127, 173, 181, 67, 120, 64, 30, 49, 47, 104, 83, 146, 118, 53, 
                98, 223, 257, 255, 292, 354, 133, 129, 140, 27, 55, 68, 148, 
                122, 132, 77, 121, 108, 109),
  rep = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
          "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
          "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
          "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3"),
  sampling_period_consecutive = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
                                  6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
                                  10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 
                                  14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16),
  sampling_period = c(-5, -5, -5, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, 
                      -1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
                      6, 11, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 34, 34, 34, 46, 46, 46, 58, 
                      58, 58)
)



You forgot to specify the nonlinear function you would like to use in your model.

I would recommend using a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) for this data. You can find a great introduction to GAMs here. I would encourage going through the link to understand what GAMs are prior to using them but they are  similar to GLMs (and implementing them is similar to the lmer notation you use). GAMs use smooth functions to model the (potential) nonlinear effect of each predictor. You can use these models like so
library(mgcv) # For creating GAMS
data$rep <- as.factor(data$rep) # convert rep variable to factor
gam.abundance <- gam(abundance ~ s(sampling_period) + s(rep, bs = "re"), 
# Use bs = "re" to specify a random intercept by replicate
                     data = data)
gam.check(gam.abundance) # diagnostics
summary(gam.abundance)
plot(gam.abundance)

See also this blog for more GAM uses and tutorials.

I'd just like to clarify that a GAM is considered a linear model, in the accepted technical sense that the model is linear in the coefficients. Linear models  can capture nonlinear associations between a predictor and outcome with predictor transformations, splines, or GAMs if the model is linear in the coefficients. Also, if the OP has only 3 levels of rep there's probably nothing to be gained with a mixed model (or bs = "re"); with fewer than about 5 levels it's typically more efficient just to use rep as a fixed predictor. (+1)

OP seems to have count data. An appropriate family and link function should be considered.

Hi @EdM and all, thank you for your valuable comments. However, I have a follow-up question. While GAM is more about visual interpretation, I’m more interested in the mechanistic aspect. I want to test whether the abundance was affected by the sampling period (i.e., month). Then, if I understand correctly, to better grasp the theoretical/mechanistic part, I could use a linear or non-linear model. Am I correct? I am interested in doing something similar to Fig. 2 here, if possible, to see differences in abundances between month: link

@Pablo you can use a linear model to evaluate how abundance differed among sampling periods. Treat sampling_period_consecutive as a multi-level factor, and use that as a predictor in your model instead of modeling time directly. The overall significance of the that multi-level factor will tell you whether abundance differed at all among sampling periods, and you can use post-modeling tools like those in the R emmeans package to compare specific sampling periods or combinations (e.g., the average pre-event against periods immediately after).

@EdM, thanks for your prompt reply.  So if I'm understanding correctly, I could define my model as model <- lmer(abundance ~ factor(sampling_period_consecutive) + (1|rep), data = data).   Then, I could finally make the comparisons with emm <- emmeans(model, "sampling_period_consecutive") and pairs(emm).

@Pablo I wold use rep as a fixed rather than a random effect if it only has 3 levels, and I’d suggest that you don’t try to evaluate all pairwise comparisons with pairs() as the large number of comparisons will lead to loss of power after correction for multiple comparisons. Limit comparisons to a few, maybe just consecutive differences or, if you have independent knowledge of the event time, maybe the average of pre-event values against each of the others. The emmeans package has tools for those types of comparisons, although they might take a bit more work to set up.

@EdM thank you very much for your help.  All your recommendations have been very valuable.
